# Convert date-time decimal

Tags: powershell

Please - how to convert DateTime decimal to DateTime standard?

My code is wrong:

```
$decimalHour = 104310
$hour=[Math]::Truncate($decimalHour)
$minute=($decimalHour - $hour) * 60
$second = [int](($minute - ([Math]::Truncate($minute))) * 60)
$minute=[Math]::Truncate($minute)
$date=[datetime]::Parse("$day_0`:$hour`:$minute`:$second")
""
""
"Jours     : " + $date.day
"Heures    : " + $date.Hour
"Minutes   : " + $date.Minute
"Secondes  : " + $date.Second
# "Times     : " + $date.ToLongTimeString()
```

Thanks Arnold

Comment: What is "*Date-Time décimale*" (to what standard/units/epoch offset does this refer)? What do you mean with "*Date-Time standard*". Please explain (in the question) what is "*wrong with your stuf"" and/or what you expect instead. See also: [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: please show what your input is AND what the desired output should be. ///// also, where is `$Day_0` set? ///// also also ... if you want to convert 10k hours to a timespan, look at this >>> `New-TimeSpan -Hours 104310` <<<

Comment: Thank's: ex Format: 3 days, 22 hours, 10 Minute. ; Arnold

Comment: What do you mean by DateTune Standard please elaborate.

Comment: Thank's: Input (from the log-files (foreach : "104310"

Comment: What does that number represent? Seconds? If so, assigning to `$decimalHour` is confusing; also, `$decimalHour - $hour` is always `0`. Please update your question to clarify.

Comment: Start-time (any) to convert time from the job give me: the decimal-time. and now: wath ist the reelle time? : days, hours, minutes. tha all Sir - Thank's -Arnold

Comment: Is This better for you: Time  55635.2   Ply 139 140   File  815254179  795943021
Maxes:  0 Error   12.2M Alloc   42 Fopen   7222.3M Write. - All file have this information. So i have also to us "foreach". Arnold

Comment: Please update the question instead of posting it in the comments.

Comment: "104310" are sec. One day have how many sec? Wath is the probleme? Thank's; Arnold

Comment: how close her my account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Construct a [`System.TimeSpan`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.TimeSpan) instance using the [`New-TimeSpan`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/new-timespan) cmdlet:

```sh
$seconds = 104310.0

$timeSpan = New-TimeSpan -Seconds ([Math]::Truncate($seconds))

$timeSpan | Select-Object Days, Hours, Minutes, Seconds
```

The above yields:

```
Days Hours Minutes Seconds
---- ----- ------- -------
   1     4      58      30
```

---

Processing multiple string values in a loop:

```sh
"104310.0", "110433" | ForEach-Object {
  New-TimeSpan -Seconds ([Math]::Truncate($_))
} | Select-Object Days, Hours, Minutes, Seconds
```